# How to sequentially browse all nodes of a TTreeView under Firemonkey and Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to browse items of a treeview, without using recursion, for performance reasons.

TTreeview provides GlobalCount and ItemByGlobalIndex methods, but it only returns *visible* items
I searched the root class code without finding a private list of all nodes, FGlobalItems seems to only holds items that need to be rendered

Is there a way to sequentially browse all items (including not visible and collapsed nodes) of a treeview?

This question applies to Delphi XE3 / FM2

Thanks,

**[Edit Feb 3]**
I accepted the default answer (not possible out of the box), despite I was looking for a way to patch the firemonkey treeview on this aspect.
After more analysis, I found out that the FGlobalItems list only holds expanded items and is maintained in the method TCustomTreeView.UpdateGlobalIndexes;
Commenting line 924 of FMX.TreeView (if AItem.IsExpanded then...) leads to building a full index of nodes, and allows to browse all nodes sequentially using ItemByGlobalIndex(), BUT could lead to other performance issues and bugs...
Without any more clue, I'll keep my recursive code.

Comment: I doubt very much that what you ask for can be done. The design of FMX is that every control can parent any other control. So you just need to iterate over the children just like any other control. Why would the framework maintain a linear version of the tree structure in parallel to the recursive version.

Comment: What makes you think avoiding recursion improves performance?

Comment: @jachguate: You avoid the cost of calls with parameters stacking and local variable create/destroy, for each browsed node. Checked with previous commercial code on large trees.

Comment: @David: On VCL side, dev expree tree for example maintains an internal list of nodes. With the FMX treeview, a sequential list is also maintained, but only for visible nodes. Why should it maintain it: even if not required, having a raw collection of items, and separate data reflecting the hierarchical structure seems a good design.

Comment: VCL is completely different. Forget all about VCL.

Comment: @user the cost of creating a stack frame to allocate parameters and local vars is usually negligible. The use of a UI control to store a large set of data and then being in need to traverse it and not the underlying structure looks like a bad design also. The UI controls IMHO are meant just to manage, well, the interaction with the user, and not to store large amounts of data.

Comment: @jachguate: You could want to make the node matching a current object, visible and expanded. In this case, you need to browse all nodes, check if it is connected to the searched object, and expand it if so. A bad design would be to maintain a dependency from business objects to tree nodes. Maintaining a dependency from tree nodes to business objects (through the TagObject property) seems ok. I dont get the point about the bad design here?

Comment: You can walk the tree by creating NextItem and PrevItem functions in a non-recursive manner. I have code if this is of interest.

Comment: Thanks Mike, yes a workaround would be great. Just curious: Do you expand the node on demand inside your NextItem method?

Comment: IsExpanded only relates to what is on display, the tree of nodes is always the same - always contains every node. See my answer below.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then you can solve this using a class helper. That way you can either build a list of all the tree nodes (visible ones, and invisible ones alike), but you can also wrap it in a method for looping through all the nodes using anonymous procedure (reference to procedure). For code sample see my answer (and let me know if that suits your criteria): https://stackoverflow.com/a/73493390/7544123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my functions for walking a treeview in a non-recursive manner. Simple to use if you have a node and want to move to the next or previous one without having to walk the entire tree.

GetNextItem functions by looking at it's first child, or if no children, looking at it's parent for the next child after itself (and going further through parents as necessary).

GetPrevItem looks at the parent to find the previous item, and uses GetLastChild to find the last child of that item (which does use recursion, BTW).

Note that the code as written only walk Expanded nodes, but can easily be modified to walk all nodes (just remove references to IsExpanded).

```
function GetLastChild(Item: TTreeViewItem): TTreeViewItem;
begin
  if (Item.IsExpanded) and (Item.Count > 0) then
    Result := GetLastChild(Item.Items[Item.Count-1])
  else
    Result := Item;
end;

function GetNextItem(Item: TTreeViewItem): TTreeViewItem;
var ItemParent: TTreeViewItem;
  I: Integer;
  TreeViewParent: TTreeView;
  Parent: TFMXObject;
  Child: TFMXObject;
begin
  if Item = nil then
    Result := nil
  else if (Item.IsExpanded) and (Item.Count > 0) then
    Result := Item.Items[0]
  else
  begin
    Parent := Item.Parent;
    Child := Item;
    while (Parent <> nil) and not (Parent is TTreeView) do
    begin
      while (Parent <> nil) and not (Parent is TTreeView) and not (Parent is TTreeViewItem) do
        Parent := Parent.Parent;

      if (Parent <> nil) and (Parent is TTreeViewItem) then
      begin
        ItemParent := TTreeViewItem(Parent);
        I := 0;
        while (I < ItemParent.Count) and (ItemParent.Items[I] <> Child) do
          inc(I);
        inc(I);
        if I < ItemParent.Count then
        begin
          Result := ItemParent.Items[I];
          EXIT;
        end;
        Child := Parent;
        Parent := Parent.Parent
      end;
    end;

    if (Parent <> nil) and (Parent is TTreeView) then
    begin
      TreeViewParent := TTreeView(Parent);
      I := 0;
      while (I < TreeViewParent.Count) and (TreeViewParent.Items[I] <> Item) do
        inc(I);
      inc(I);
      if I < TreeViewParent.Count then
        Result := TreeViewParent.Items[I]
      else
      begin
        Result := Item;
        EXIT;
      end;
    end
    else
      Result := Item
  end
end;

function GetPrevItem(Item: TTreeViewItem): TTreeViewItem;
var Parent: TFMXObject;
  ItemParent: TTreeViewItem;
  TreeViewParent: TTreeView;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Item = nil then
    Result := nil
  else
  begin
    Parent := Item.Parent;
    while (Parent <> nil) and not (Parent is TTreeViewItem) and not (Parent is TTreeView) do
      Parent := Parent.Parent;

    if (Parent <> nil) and (Parent is TTreeViewItem) then
    begin
      ItemParent := TTreeViewItem(Parent);
      I := 0;
      while (I < ItemParent.Count) and (ItemParent.Items[I] <> Item) do
        inc(I);
      dec(I);
      if I >= 0 then
        Result := GetLastChild(ItemParent.Items[I])
      else
        Result := ItemParent;
    end
    else if (Parent <> nil) and (Parent is TTreeView) then
    begin
      TreeViewParent := TTreeView(Parent);
      I := 0;
      while (I < TreeViewParent.Count) and (TreeViewParent.Items[I] <> Item) do
        inc(I);
      dec(I);
      if I >= 0 then
        Result := GetLastChild(TreeViewParent.Items[I])
      else
        Result := Item
    end
    else
      Result := Item;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach

Answer (score 3):

The question essentially asks how to traverse a tree without recursion. There are many ways to traverse a tree; the fact that your tree happens to be represented with nodes in a visual control is irrelevant.

For some algorithms, it's easier to think of the traversal in recursive terms. That way, you let the programming language keep track of where in the tree you are by keeping the currently active node as an argument on the stack. If you don't want to use recursion, then you simply have to keep track of the progress yourself. Common tools for that include stacks and queues.

A preorder traversal means that when you visit a node, you do your action on that node's data before doing the action on the node's children. It corresponds to visiting each node of a tree-view control from top to bottom. You could implement it like this with a stack:

```
procedure PreorderVisit(Node: TTreeNode; Action: TNodeAction);
var
  Worklist: TStack<TTreeNode>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Worklist := TStack<TTreeNode>.Create;
  try
    Worklist.Push(Node);
    repeat
      Node := Worklist.Pop;
      for i := Pred(Node.Items.Count) downto 0 do
        Worklist.Push(Node.Items[i]);
      Action(Node);
    until Worklist.Empty;
  finally
    Worklist.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Push the children onto the stack in reverse order so they'll be popped off in the desired order.

In that code, `Action` stands for whatever task you need to do with each node. You can either use it as specified in the code, as an external function, or you can write a specialized version of `PreorderVisit` that includes the task-specific code.

TTreeView doesn't actually represent a *tree*, though. It's really a *forest* (a collection of trees). That's because there is no single node that represents the root. You can easily use the function above to process all the nodes in a tree, though:

```
procedure PreorderVisitTree(Tree: TTreeView; Action: TNodeAction);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Pred(Tree.Items.Count) do
    PreorderVisit(Tree.Items[i], Action);
end;
```

---

Another way of doing a preorder traversal that takes advantage of the specific structure of TTreeView is to use the built-in `GetNext` method of each node:

```
procedure PreorderVisitTree(Tree: TTreeView; Action: TNodeAction);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  if Tree.Items.Count = 0 then
    exit;
  Node := Tree.Items[0];
  repeat
    Action(Node);
    Node := Node.GetNext;
  until not Assigned(Node);
end;
```

---

There appears to be no way of getting hidden nodes of a Firemonkey tree view. You might find better results by iterating over your internal tree data structure instead of trying to extract information from the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid that managing manually a stack instead of letting the compiler do it for us has no added value, at least for performance constraints. Regarding your second proposal, TTreeViewItem does not have a GetNext method (my question is related to firemonkey)

Comment: The compiler never does anything for you related to visual controls. That is always in library code. Whether that is written by you, or is part of FMX likely makes little difference to performance. Would you accept an answer that says that FMX does not have the functionality you are asking for?

Comment: @David: The compiler generates code to push parameters to the stack. When you use recursion, this code is executed. Rob's proposal is to rewrite what the compiler does, but with our own code, using the Worklist instead of the stack&heap. This has nothing to do with FMX and I never wrote it. I see that FMX seems to not have the functionality out of the box. I was asking for any workaround through class helper or even direct update of FMX code...

Comment: So now you are saying that you don't mind using recursion? You are saying that recursion is fine so long as the stack used is the thread stack rather than a user-defined stack. The thing is you asked for non-recursive solution, and Rob has given the only possible non-recursive solution. Perhaps you could tell us what your performance constraints are.

Comment: err.. no, there is a misunderstanding, I do mind to avoid recursion cost. I say that Rob's proposal does not provide better performance than the original recursion, because it re-creates the recursion mecanism. I'll accept Rob solution as a default answer (not possible out of the box), but I was looking for a workaround: see my comment in the question

Answer (score 1):

In XE8 this works for me:

```
function GetNextItem(Item: TTreeViewItem): TTreeViewItem;
var
   Parent: TFMXObject;
   Child: TTreeViewItem;
begin
    Result := nil;
    if Item.Count > 0 then
        Result := Item.Items[0]
    else
    begin
        Parent := Item.ParentItem;
        Child := Item;
        while (Result = nil) and (Parent <> nil) do
        begin
           if Parent is TTreeViewItem then
           begin
               if TTreeViewItem(Parent).Count > (Child.Index + 1) then
                   Result := TTreeViewItem(Parent).Items[Child.Index + 1]
               else
               begin
               Child := TTreeViewItem(Parent);
               if Child.ParentItem <> nil then
                   Parent := Child.ParentItem
               else
                   Parent := Child.TreeView;
               end;
           end
           else
           begin
            if TTreeView(Parent).Count > Child.Index + 1 then
                Result := TTreeView(Parent).Items[Child.Index + 1]
            else
                Parent := nil;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Item.ParentItem` can also be nil! That is why I had replaced the line `Parent := Item.ParentItem` with the following lines:

```
  if Item.ParentItem <> nil then
    Parent := Item.ParentItem
  else
    Parent := Item.TreeView;
```

The complete function `GetNextItem` after the correction:

```
function GetNextItem(Item: TTreeViewItem): TTreeViewItem;
var
  Parent: TFMXObject;
  Child: TTreeViewItem;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if Item.Count > 0 then
    Result := Item.Items[0]
  else begin
    if Item.ParentItem <> nil then
      Parent := Item.ParentItem
    else
      Parent := Item.TreeView;
    Child := Item;
    while (Result = nil) and (Parent <> nil) do
    begin
      if Parent is TTreeViewItem then
      begin
        if TTreeViewItem(Parent).Count > (Child.Index + 1) then
          Result := TTreeViewItem(Parent).Items[Child.Index + 1]
        else begin
          Child := TTreeViewItem(Parent);
          if Child.ParentItem <> nil then
            Parent := Child.ParentItem
          else
            Parent := Child.TreeView;
        end;
      end else begin
        if TTreeView(Parent).Count > Child.Index + 1 then
          Result := TTreeView(Parent).Items[Child.Index + 1]
        else
          Parent := nil;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Tested at Delphi 10.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I would add a function to SEARCH PARTIALLY a text into a TreeView, from a TEdit (Search) placed up from the TreeView (TV). (special thank to the previous post which this answer is based from)

This work perfectly using Enter to start the search and F3 to continue searching.

```
// SEARCH ITEM (text partially or by particular ID in item.tag)

function GetNextItem(Item: TTreeViewItem): TTreeViewItem;
var
  Parent: TFMXObject;
  Child: TTreeViewItem;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if Item.Count > 0 then
    Result := Item.Items[0]
  else begin
    if Item.ParentItem <> nil then
      Parent := Item.ParentItem
    else
      Parent := Item.TreeView;
    Child := Item;
    while (Result = nil) and (Parent <> nil) do
    begin
      if Parent is TTreeViewItem then
      begin
        if TTreeViewItem(Parent).Count > (Child.Index + 1) then
          Result := TTreeViewItem(Parent).Items[Child.Index + 1]
        else begin
          Child := TTreeViewItem(Parent);
          if Child.ParentItem <> nil then
            Parent := Child.ParentItem
          else
            Parent := Child.TreeView;
        end;
      end else begin
        if TTreeView(Parent).Count > Child.Index + 1 then
          Result := TTreeView(Parent).Items[Child.Index + 1]
        else
          Parent := nil;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;


function FindItem(aFromItem : TTreeViewItem ; Value: String = '' ; aID : integer = -1) : TTreeViewItem;
var I: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;

  while aFromItem.Index < aFromITem.TreeView.Count do
  begin
    aFromItem := GetNextItem(aFromItem);
    if aFromItem <> nil then
    begin
      if (aID <> -1) and (aFromItem.Tag = aID) then
      begin
        Result := aFromItem;
        EXIT;
      end
      else if pos(Value, uppercase(aFromItem.Text)) > 0 then
      begin
        Result := aFromItem;
        EXIT;
      end;
    end
    else
      exit;
  end;
end;


procedure TCListeMedia.SearchKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  i : integer;
  vSearch : string;
begin
  if (Key = 13) or (Key = vkF3) then
  begin
    // Search or continue to search
    vSearch := Uppercase(Search.Text);
    if Key = 13 then
    begin
      i := 0;
      if TV.Count > 0 then
      begin
        if pos(vSearch, uppercase(TV.Items[0].Text)) > 0 then
          TV.Selected := TV.Items[0]
        else
          TV.Selected := FindItem(TV.Items[0], vSearch);
      end;
    end
    else if TV.Selected <> nil then
    begin
      i := 1 + TV.Selected.Index;
      TV.Selected := FindItem(TV.Selected, vSearch);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TCListeMedia.TVKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = vkF3) then
    SearchKeyDown(Sender, Key, KeyChar, Shift);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made this function for my project is fast and easy you can try it

```
function FindItem(const TreeView: TTreeView; const Value: Variant): TTreeViewItem;

      function ItemExist(const AItem: TTreeViewItem): Boolean;
      begin
           Result:= False;

           if AItem <> nil then
           begin
                {Set your condition here}
                if AItem.Text = Value then
                begin
                     FindItem:= AItem;
                     Exit(True);
                end;

                var I: Integer;
                for I := 0 to AItem.Count - 1 do
                begin
                     if ItemExist( AItem.ItemByIndex(I)) then
                          Break;
                end;
           end;
      end;

  var
    AItem: TTreeViewItem;
    I: Integer;
  begin
       Result:= nil;

       for I := 0 to TreeView.Count - 1 do
       begin
            AItem:= TreeView.ItemByIndex(I);
            if ItemExist(AItem) or (Result <> nil) then Break;
       end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I take advantage of class helpers and anonymous procedures in Delphi to loop through items in a TreeView. This can be easilly extended to build an index list.

My class helper goes like this:

```
{ TTreeViewHelper }
  TTreeViewHelper
  = Class helper for FMX.TreeView.TTreeView
      Public
        Procedure LoopThroughItems(const Func: TProc<TTreeViewItem>; const AExpandedOnly: Boolean);
    End;

  Procedure TTreeViewHelper.LoopThroughItems(const Func: TProc<TTreeViewItem>; const AExpandedOnly: Boolean);
    var
      i : integer;
      procedure ProcessItem(const AItem: TTreeViewItem);
        var
          I: Integer;
        begin
          if(AItem=nil) then exit;
          Func(AItem);
          for I := 0 to AItem.Count - 1 do ProcessItem(AItem.ItemByIndex(I));
        end;
    begin
      if not Assigned(Func)then exit;
      if(GlobalCount<1)then exit;
      if(AExpandedOnly)
        then for i:=0 to Count-1 do Func(self.Items[i])
        else for i:=0 to Count-1 do ProcessItem(ItemByGlobalIndex(i));
    end;
```

And I am using it like this:

```
  TreeView1.LoopThroughItems(
    procedure(E: TTreeViewItem)
    begin 
      if Assigned(E)and(E is TTreeNode)
        then TN := E as TTreeNode { My own subclass }
        else exit;
      if Assigned(TN.DataObject)and(TN.DataObject is TIOTSensorData)
        then IOT := TN.DataObject as TIOTSensorData
        else exit;
      if(IOT<>AFormula)then exit;
      TreeView1.Selected := TN;
    end,
    False
  );
```

The sample above is from my actual project, you would use your own logic in the anonymous procedure, but the really neat part is the last `TreeView1.Selected := TN;`, becasue even if the TN is a non-visible item, the TreeView will select it and expand all its parent nodes.

Now, you say you want to avoid recursion, but actually you want to avoid a recursive recursion. Because you'll have to build your index first, and while building it is okay to use recursion one time in there.
Following the same approach, just go ahead and add a new method to your class helper:

```
{ TTreeViewHelper }
  TTreeViewHelper
  = Class helper for FMX.TreeView.TTreeView
      Public
        Procedure LoopThroughItems(const Func: TProc<TTreeViewItem>; const AExpandedOnly: Boolean);
        Function  BuildFullIndex: TList<TTreeViewItem>;
    End;

  Function  TTreeViewHelper.BuildFullIndex: TList<TTreeViewItem>;
    var
      i : integer;
      procedure Publish(const AItem: TTreeViewItem);
        var
          I: Integer;
        begin
          if(AItem=nil) then exit;
          Result.Add(AItem);
          for I := 0 to AItem.Count - 1 do Publish(AItem.ItemByIndex(I));
        end;
    begin
      Result := TList<TTreeViewItem>.Create;
      if(GlobalCount<1)then exit;
      for i:=0 to Count-1 do Publish(ItemByGlobalIndex(i))
    end;
```

And use it like this:

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

var
  Index : TList<TTreeViewItem>;
begin
  Index := Formulas.BuildFullIndex; 
  try
    if(Index.Count<1)then exit;
    for i:=0 to Index.Count-1 do
      begin
        { do your thing here }
      end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Index);
  end;
end;
```

Cheers!